# Questions about seforim recommendations?

Tags: support, scope

Figured I'd ask here before posting to main. I'm looking for an english translation of the mishna berura. Is that a question ("What's a good english translation...?") that's allowed on here? I know some other sites disallow "shopping" questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This has never been well-codified here on Meta, but the practice here has been to welcome [product-recommendation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-recommendation) questions and require that the question specify criteria sufficiently for readers to make an objective determination, based on the description in a well-written answer, of how well a particular product fits the request. Note the summary on the [product-recommendation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-recommendation) tag, and see un-closed, high-scoring questions there for best practices.